# overriding SQL Server operator from job

Tags: sql-server

I need to sometimes override a query in a SP, sometime i need where x = x and sometimes use where x <> x.
is logic such as this allowed:

```
DECLARE @Operator VARCHAR(1);

SET @Operator = '='

IF 'X' @Operator 'Y'
PRINT 'Yes'
ELSE
PRINT 'No'
```

Answer (score 1):

**Use Dyanmic SQL**

try like this:

```
DECLARE @Operator VARCHAR(1);

SET @Operator = '='

DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)='
IF ''X'' '+@Operator+' ''Y''
PRINT ''Yes''
ELSE
PRINT ''No''
'
exec(@SQL)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
No
```